# Create a function in python, which given an integer returns a string. For example:- 1 maps to a, 26 to z, 27 to aa, 50 to ax

Tags: python, python-3.x, function

I want to create a function in python. The function will accept an integer and return a string.
The mapping rule can be explained by some examples as shown below:-

Example
1 maps to 'a', 26 maps to 'z', 27 maps to 'aa', 50 maps to 'ax', and 70 maps to 'br'

The sequence is - a, b, c, d till z, aa, ab, ca till zz, aaa, aab, aac till zzz.

I was able to create this function:-

```
from string import ascii_lowercase
import itertools

def func(n):
    c = 0
    l = []
    for size in itertools.count(1):
        for s in itertools.product(ascii_lowercase, repeat=size):
            l.append(s)
            c+=1
            if c == n:
                return l
```

**EDIT: SOLUTION**

Thanks a lot for the help everyone.
I came up with a solution to the problem:

```
d = { n-96:chr(n) for n in range(97,123) }

def div(n):
    if ((n%26) == 0 and n>26):
        return func(n//26 - 1)
    elif (n//26) <= 0:
        return ''
    elif n == 26:
        return 'z'
    elif (n//26) in d:
        return d[n//26]
    else:
        return func(n//26)

def mod(n):
    if n<=0:
        return ''
    elif ((n%26) == 0 and n>26):
        return 'z'
    elif (n%26)<=0:
        return ''
    else:
        return d[n%26]

def func(n):

    res_div = div(n)
    res_mod = mod(n)
    return (res_div + res_mod)
```

Comment: Rules are not explained by examples. If you don't understand the rule well enough to define it rigorously, it is not likely that you will be able come up with a solution.

Comment: you should first show what you tried and not just require answer from other people, with no effort

Comment: SO isn’t a service to do your homework - please check here [How to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: @batman567, I know SO is not a service to get solutions to my homework. I tried solving the problem but couldn't come up with an optimized solution. You should not assume anything. Same for Jakub Doka

Comment: Are you certain that `70` maps to `'be'`? According to your description, excluding `'be'`, the mapped value should be `57` because `'be'` is 7 elements after `'ax'` in the sequence you describe.

Comment: / and % if you know what I mean...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks a lot for the help everyone.
I came up with a solution to the problem:

```
d = { n-96:chr(n) for n in range(97,123) }

def div(n):
    if ((n%26) == 0 and n>26):
        return func(n//26 - 1)
    elif (n//26) <= 0:
        return ''
    elif n == 26:
        return 'z'
    elif (n//26) in d:
        return d[n//26]
    else:
        return func(n//26)

def mod(n):
    if n<=0:
        return ''
    elif ((n%26) == 0 and n>26):
        return 'z'
    elif (n%26)<=0:
        return ''
    else:
        return d[n%26]

def func(n):

    res_div = div(n)
    res_mod = mod(n)
    return (res_div + res_mod)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try implementing something like this. Let's say we have 28. We do 28//26 and get 2. Then we do 28//26 and get the first digit 1. So we map it to a number like 12 (26 representing tens places). Then we split the number, anything with a one gets replaced by an a and anything with a 2 gets represented by a b so on and so forth.

Answer (score 0):

It's important to understand that this problem is fundamentally converting a number to a different base. There is no need to count up to the value of `n`, it may be calculated. This is accomplished for base26 to base10 with the same process used for converting base2 to base 10.

Consider converting the binary number `1010` to decimal, assuming that the leftmost digit is the most significant. Starting from the rightmost digit, sum the values obtained by multiplying each digit by increasing powers of 2. `0*2^0 + 1*2^1 + 0*2^2 + 1*2^3 = 0 + 2 + 0 + 8 = 10`. This may be verified:

```py
int("1010", 2)
```

So the steps to do this for your problem are:

1. Map a, b, ..., z to `int`S 1, 2, ..., 26
2. Reverse `n`
3. Perform calculation

```py
def convert_abc_to_dec(abc):
    import string
    a_to_i_map = {c: i+1 for i, c in enumerate(string.ascii_lowercase)}
    return sum(a_to_i_map[x]*(26**i) for i, x in enumerate(n[::-1]))
```